# React: Design web application as per desktop display scaling percentage

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web-applications

I design my web application(React) as per my system settings which is 125% Zoom and 1920*1080 resolution. But many of the clients system has 150% with same resolution. Because of this the application gets zoomed and in some cases the design breaks which is expected.
I checked many questions related to this and many spoke about adjusting the font size. My application has many images and custom elements. How would you normally design you application with CSS or bootstrap to handle these conditions or what would you recommend me to do in these cases or how should be my application design.
The setting I meant is attached here
[image]

Comment: I guess I got it.. from what i could see is when the scaling percentage increase the browser viewport width also changes(width decreases). so i can handle these with media queries. 
If anyone has any other way pls do suggest.. thank you!